# Adding with Recursion

Tags: python-3.x, function, recursion

I'm trying to find the sum between two functions using a recursive function. Here's what I've got so far:

```
def add(a, b):
    if zero(a):
       return b
    if zero(b):
       return a
    else:
       return add(decr(a), incr(b))
```

zero(a): determine if a function is 0 or not

decr(a): a function that increments a by 1 (a + 1)

incr(a): a function that decrements a by 1 (a - 1)

In running this function, I get the answer I'm looking for,
calling add(5, 6) for example does give me 11, I just don't understand at all how it gets this answer. In other words, I got it by complete accident. 
If someone could explain what is going on here, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Really, you just mashed the keyboard and the correct answer came out? You should buy a lottery ticket!

Comment: Just take it step by step.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code? Either with the debugger or on paper?

Comment: So are we pretending this isn't just a homework question then? It's not a very good question either, because it doesn't work if `a` is negative. If `b` is positive, then the condition of `zero(b)` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

At every step you are decrementing **a** by 1 and incrementing **b** by 1. 
Basically what you are doing is decomposing **a** into `(1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1)` a times.

So what is doing is instead of doing `a + b` you do `b + 1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1 (a times)`

Comment: So if I wanted to use this idea for a function that multiplied two numbers, I'd try and use the same method? For example
5, 6. So I'd have to find a way to do b + 6 +6 +6 ... + 6 (a times, in this case, 5). Right?